# Cognito Auth Works in Prod but Not locally

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So this will be a brief explanation since I've got no idea what is going on or how to solve it. So lately I've been asked to work on a project (React frontend) that uses amplify with Cognito for auth, the only problem I've had lately is that my local environment does not do the authentication for some reason. I've noticed that the prod website whenever it does a request for Sign In uses a certain ClientId but in my local enviroment uses a whole different one. I know for a fact the code is the same in prod and in my machine since I've done a lot of tests with amplify. So does anyone have a clue what is happening or what to do to make it work locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we work with Amplify there are certain steps that needs to be taken to setup the local environment. Your amplify project must first pull down the resources that it has created. In your case the Cognito Auth resource.
To do that run the command `amplify pull` this will read the `team-provider-info.json` file in your amplify project and build the configs required for you to work locally. This is under the assumption that you have after pulling the code down initialised the amplify project using `amplify init` command.
The following docs should guide you in this regard [Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/overview/)